# Converting from different values to Enum value

Tags: java, enums

My application gets external data which needs to be translated to a corresponding Enum value. This was my first approach:

```
public enum Side {
    LEFT,
    RIGHT;

    public static Side fromByte(Byte b) throws Exception {
        switch(b)
        {
            case 'l':
                return LEFT;
            case 'r':
                return RIGHT;
            default:
                throw new Exception("not a valid byte");
        }
    }
}
```

Is this okay, or is there a more idiomatic way to do this?

**Note:** Ignore the byte to char comparison and the very generic exception throw, i will look into that later - especially the char and byte type conversion. Seems to be a bigger deal than i originally anticipated.

Comment: Why is parameter a `Byte` and not a `byte`, if you don't check for null anyway?

Comment: @Andreas I get the Parameter from some generated JNA code and that returns a `Byte`

Comment: Java will do auto-unboxing if you have a `Byte` and need a `byte`, so don't make the contract of this method dependent on how your caller gets it's value. If some other caller has a `byte` and want to call this method, you're forcing the compiler to box it on the call, just to unbox it inside the method on the `switch` statement. Change to `byte`, and no boxing/unboxing will occur if caller has a `byte`. In short, take the value you want, not the value your caller might have.

Comment: Good to know, I will do that right now!

Comment: @SMA  using map will mean extra memory . Though Map should be considered if there are large number of cases

Comment: @MSach Think from scalability perspective. See the answer by hamo below where you pay the penalty on time by looping over all the values of enum and doing comparison i.e. space vs time complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually go for something like this,

```
public enum Side
{
    LEFT('l'),
    RIGHT('r');

    private byte byteValue;

    private Side(byte byteValue)
    {
        this.byteValue = byteValue;
    }

    public byte getByteValue()
    {
        return byteValue;
    }

    public static Side findByByteValue(byte value)
    {
        for(Side side : values())
        {
            if(side.byteValue == value)
            {
                return side;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note the byteValue of LEFT and RIGHT are not bytes and you need to either change them to their byte values or handle the conversion beforehand and change byteValue to char.

Comment: I like this approach! If you have multiple different sources (lets say the characters 'r' and 'l' and the ints 0 (left) and 1 (right)), would you do it like i did above then, or would you perform some conversion and use a common type as the storage?

Comment: I will have to look into the conversion to byte somewhere on Stackoverflow. I get my values from a C API over a JNA binding. And a char has 8bit there, which is in turn translated to a Byte object on the Java side. Maybe I can simply use the ascii values without doing some fancy conversion stuff, since i only need 'l' and 'r' anyways.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but if you wanted to also add 0 and 1 to LEFT and RIGHT respectively, you could do this, `LEFT('l', 0), RIGHT('r', 1)` and then add an int field, `private int intValue` and a getter and find method for the int value also.

Comment: Yes, that's what i was getting at. Java enums are so powerful compared to C++ ones, i still don't think about them as classes. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Approach looks good. But if there is a possibility of a large of cases then consider using map(implementation can be HashMap in your case) as it will be more readable and lesser code.